# Facebook and suggestions

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to write a simple application that finds out who liked your page. I used FQL and a query very similar to:

```
$query = 'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="149187568469862"';
```

The first issue is that FB returns an empty array. Maybe the data will be available in the near future.

I will describe the most important issue. If the user X liked my page, I would like to know who suggested X to like my page. Maybe nobody, but there are chances that X pressed "Like" after a suggestion coming from a friend. I browsed the documentation, but I didn't find relevant information about how can I see who liked my page as a result of a suggestion. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can not retrieve any historical information on who referred a "like". Furthermore, as of right now facebook does not seem to allow querying for all your pages "fans" (which is basically everyone who likes your page). They do, however allow looking up all pages that a user "likes" using fql. Much of their documentation is very "skinny" on examples. I actually learned the most by downloading the facebook connect javascript toolkit which came with some client side examples of the most used functionality. https://github.com/facebook/connect-js  - this may be a good place to start